# WCF Service "Endpoint not found" error

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm trying to create a RESTful service that returns data in Json format but when I open it in my browser it says "Endpoint not found."

My web.config look like this

```
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="RestService.HelloWorldService">
    <!--<endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="REST"  contract="RestService.IHelloWorldService">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="REST" contract="RestService.IHelloWorldService" />-->
    <endpoint address="json" binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="REST"  contract="RestService.IHelloWorldService" />        
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:52478/HelloWorldService.svc" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="REST">
      <webHttp/>
    </behavior>
  <!--<behavior name="SOAPDemoEndpointBehavior">
  <soapProcessing/>
</behavior>-->
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>          
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>          
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>  
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

and here is the code

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IHelloWorldService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
        UriTemplate = "json/{id}")]
    string JsonData(string id);
}
```

I've even tried to start the project (via F5, or Ctrl F5) and then navigating to page, as one answer here on stackoverflow suggested that, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: why the negative vote?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem. I had given the address a name for the endpoint in the web.config file and also in the UriTemplate I added json/ before {id}. I needed to remove one of them and then it works.